# How to limit the size of an '<li>' element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement something to limit the size of a `<li>`. The function is that you can write an article with n characters but it should be displayed only 500character then I want to put a button like read more.

For the moment I have the button who comes if the text is 500characters but I can't  find how to limit the size...

Someone could give me advices ?

Comment: You'll need to post your code.

Comment: @Panda I think it's useless...what could I show you ? The HTML code ?

Comment: are you familiar with javascripts substring function ?

Comment: @madalinivascu no I'm not but I open to learn a new things :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use substring to get only a subset of chars entered and redisplay that on mouseover

On MouseOver use substring to change text inside li tag.

```
var myLi = $('#your-li-id');
myLi.text(myLi.text().substring(0,500))
```

Comment: I know bro just need to wait because of stackoverflow rules ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with jQuery. Look at this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = $("#count").text().length;
    var max = 5 // Max chars inside the li
    if (count > max) {
     $("#count").text($("#count").text().slice( 0, max ));
     $("#count").append(" read more..."); // Add here your button or whatever you like.
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="count">1234567890</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Patrick thank you for the help it's an good method but I used the one of @AurA (I upvote yours because it still a great one)

Comment: Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could style it with some CSS? Like with: (you have to define it's width either)

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

And than with jquery change class only on button click and then in CSS show full article?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I used the solution of @AurA

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
<li id="demo">Some lenghty string goes here</li>
function myFunction() {
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}myFunction();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/AwadheshVerma/7r4nac49/

if you want to on click:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

function myFunction() {
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```